# how to convert spauditentry to xml file

Tags: spaudit

I have this `SPAuditEntryCollection` object where in the entries are coming in XML format. I need to convert this to excel.

But before tha,t do I need to convert that to XML file so that I then read the XML file and convert to excel?

Is there any direct way I can convert to excel?

Answer (score 0):

In fact [SPAuditEntryCollection.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spauditentrycollection.tostring.aspx) method already returns **XML String** that represents audit entries:

```
<AuditData>
  <AuditEntry>
    ...
  </AuditEntry>
  ...
</AuditData>
```

Example: Load Site Collection audit entries and save into file

```
public static void SaveSiteAuditEntries(SPSite site,string fileName)
{
    var auditQry = new SPAuditQuery(site);
    var auditEntries = site.Audit.GetEntries(auditQry);
    var count = auditEntries.Count; //Ensure Data is loaded

    var docAuditEntries = new XmlDocument();
    docAuditEntries.LoadXml(auditEntries.ToString());
    docAuditEntries.Save(fileName);
}
```